# Apache + Laravel Projects with xip.io

Tags: apache, laravel, xip.io

I have 2 laravel projects with the vhost

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName project1.local
    ServerAlias project1.*.xip.io
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/project1"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName project2.local
    ServerAlias project2.*.xip.io
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/project2"
</VirtualHost>
```

If I open project2 and then project1, I get always the content of project2 back.

The root of my apache

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data www-data 4096 Mar 19 20:58 apps
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data  177 Feb 13 20:04 index.html
lrwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data   21 Apr  9 08:20 phpmyadmin -> /usr/share/phpmyadmin
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root     root       53 Apr 23 15:48 project1 -> /home/mav/Development    project1/public
lrwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data   21 Apr  9 08:21 phpsysinfo -> /usr/share/phpsysinfo
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root     root       55 Apr 23 15:45 project2 -> /home/mav/Development/project2/public
```

Answer (score 1):

That was the trick: sudo php5dismod opcache